# How do I render a 404 page in NextJS in development and production?

Tags: http-status-code-404, next.js

I have a situation where I am using nextjs for client-side and the '404 - page not found error' only appears in local development, but I would like to see it on dev and on production.
How can I archive this?

Found some examples on the net that worked well locally but didn't work again on dev and prod since I could get the statusCode locally from ctx.res.statusCode from the getInitialProps method in _app.js and display the default nextjs Error component if the status code is 404.

I also created a custom _errors.js page, but this also works in local dev only

Reusing the built-in error page :

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import Error from 'next/error';
import Page from '../components/Page';
import withData from '../lib/withData';

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    const { res } = ctx;

    const errorCode = res.statusCode > 200 ? res.statusCode : false;

    pageProps.query = ctx.query;

    return {
      pageProps,
      errorCode,
    };
  }

  render() {

    const { Component, apollo, pageProps, errorCode } = this.props;
    if (errorCode) {
      return <Error statusCode={errorCode} />;
    }

    return (
      <Container>
        <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
          <Page>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Page>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default withData(MyApp);
```

Custom error handling solution :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Error extends React.Component {
  static getInitialProps({ res, err }) {

    let errCode = null;

    if (res.statusCode) {
      errCode = res.statusCode;
    } else if (err.statusCode) {
      errCode = err.statusCode;
    }
    return { errCode };
  }

  render() {
    const { errCode } = this.props;
    return <p>{errCode ? `An error ${errCode} occurred on server` : 'An error occurred on client'}</p>;
  }
}

Error.propTypes = {
  errCode: PropTypes.number,
};

export default Error;
```

Comment: Have you a custom server and `start` script controlling your server-side processes?